# Preserve evidence of intrusion / deleted executable?

Tags: linux, security, process, executable

If you are faced with a non-root remote command execution vulnerability, and there is a foreign executable that's running on your Linux system from a user with only non-administrator privileges, what's the best way to preserve the executable and its state, and terminate the access?

The executable file itself is marked as deleted, so, it's not possible to simply make a copy of it.  Additionally, since it appears that the `exe` file within the respective `/proc/%d` directory is merely a symlink, and the executable itself is not one of the files open within `/proc/%d/fd`, it seems like even saving the executable file itself might be a bit tricky.

**How do you save all states associated with the executable for future analysis, as well as the executable itself?**

Answer (score 5):

You can freeze it with `kill -STOP $pid`. The process statistics will remain accessable through `/proc/$pid`, but it will not be executing.

You can get access to the executable file with `cp /proc/$pid/exe /destination/path`.

Comment: That's the thing -- the cp won't work, since it's a regular symlink, and the file it points to has been deleted.

Comment: @cnst try it...

Comment: hm, interesting, it does seem to work!  weird.

Comment: Is there a way to save the state, so that it can be restored later on?  The `kill -STOP` seems like a good solution, but appears to be temporary in nature.

Comment: Depends on what you're after. Your options are basically limited to taking a gcore of the process, and/or grabbing the wanted info from `/proc/$pid` and storing it somewhere (you can't just recursively copy everything).

Comment: Actually, there is another option, [CRIU](http://criu.org/)

Comment: @cnst The symlinks in `/proc/$pid/` are somewhat magic, they work even if their textual target would be invalid, like `/path/to/foo (deleted)` or `pipe:[123456789]`.